# Mock class instantiation with another class

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm sure I've looked over an answer that would solve my problem but I'm unable to find anything that helps me mock a class that's being instantiated. Consider the following code

```
import { container } from '../db/some-config';
import DaoClass from '../db/some-db-dao';

const dao = new DaoClass(container)

export function getAllThings() {
  return dao.getAll();
}

export function getThingById(id: string) {
  return dao.getById(id);
}
```

How can I mock the instantiation of `new DaoClass(container)` with a `MockDao` class that we have?

I currently have `jest.mock('../db/some-config', jest.fn());` that handles the mocking of the `container` import. However, when I try to mock the creation of the MockDao with the following:

```
jest.mock('../db/db-dao', jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return new MockDao()
}));
```

I get an error that says "Cannot read property 'container' of undefined at line: `const dao = new DBDao(marketSegmentContainer)`

I think this is a fairly simple question and I'm just missing something. Thank you in advance.